# AUFS on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

Is there a way to have AUFS on Debian Wheezy? The "tools" package is there, but I cannot find the kernel module and it doesn't seem to be included in the stock kernel.

greg

Comment: You can easily use a more recent kernel, if you know one that has it. Alternatively, jessie will be out soon.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot, I'm using OpenVZ which doesn't even support kernel 3.x that's why I was interested in AUFS I understand it's compatible with old kernels...

Comment: You mean 3.x does not support OpenVZ? That will be a problem for you, since using older kernels indefinitely is an excessive maintenance burden. I suggest you consider alternative technologies.

Comment: I know :-( but I have to deal with the existing infrastructure. Can AUFS be compiled as a module on 2.x kernels?

Comment: Ok. You need to be talking to the project directly, in that case. Send a mail to autofs-users. See http://sourceforge.net/p/aufs/mailman/aufs-users/

Comment: Also, U&L (unix.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask this kind of question. Regardless, they probably could not help you either. We don't have a lot of kernel domain experts there. In any case, this is just for your future reference. SO isn't the best place for this; it isn't a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll post in the AUFS mailing list.